# Why is $k$ constant here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

$$k=\frac{f^{T}Be}{f^{T}e}\\
A=-B^{-1}L$$

e is the eigenvector of A and f is the eigenvector of L.

L is a Laplacian matrix of an undirected graph (real symmetric, singular & positive semidefinite). A is also singular.

B is also a real symmetric matrix. $B=((M^{T}GM-H)^{-1}+D)$

where D, G, H are diagonal matrices and M is an incidence matrix such that $M^{T}M = X,$

where X is a Laplacian matrix

$$e^{T}e=f^{T}f=1$$

Is there any peculiar property for k?

> **Why do I observe $k$ to be almost constant, for a particular $B$ and all possible $L$ matrices?**

For example, for a 4 node graph, when I change L and keep B constant, k is lying within values 5.5 and 7.5 for all possible L matrices.  What is the explanation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^T Be = f^T (-LA^{-1}e) = f^T (-L \frac{1}{\lambda_{A}}e) = - \frac{\lambda_L}{\lambda_A}f^Te$.

Thus the ratio is equal to $-\frac{\lambda_L}{\lambda_A}$.

Without doing more working, I would guess that if $B$ is fixed, this essentially fixes the ratio.

(Workings beneath)

$A^{-1} = -L^{-1}B$

$Ae = \lambda e$, so $\frac{1}{\lambda_{A}}e = A^{-1} e$

$Lf = \lambda_L f$ so $f^T L = \lambda_L f^T$

Comment: L is singular, so A is singular as $det(A)=detLdetB^{-1}$. If A, L were non-singular, this would have been accurate. But is there any way to get around that problem?

Comment: How accurate is it to use pseudoinverse for singular matrices A and L, so that I could use the same proof?